# 2nd time click event gives the same result as the 1st click event gives

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have one search page say default.aspx
where user can search the properties.

on page load if it's not postback following function is getting called, which takes out only 3 properties:

```
 GetDefault();
```

Syntax for GetDefault() :

```
private void GetDefault()
{
    DataTable dtProperties = Service.GetDefaultList();
}
```

if it's post back following function is getting called, which takes out all the properties :

```
GetProperties(city, state, country);
{
    DataTable dtProperties = service.GetPropertyList(city, state, country)
}
```

there is one search button using which one can search for the property.
I have implemented functionality such that, user can directly enter whole url like www.mysite.com/default.aspx?city=1&state=2 which will give him search results on page load.

On search button click following function generates the URL, which any other user can directly put on his/her browser & can get respected search results.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TO build URL
    string RootUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WEBROOT"];

    String target_url = "";
    if ((Request.Form["search_by_city"])!= "")
    {
        string cityName = service.getCityByID(Int32.Parse(search_by_city.Value)).ToString();            
        target_url += "&city=" + cityName;
    }
    else
    {
        city = 0;
    }

    if ((Request.Form["search_by_state"]) != "")
    {
            string stateName= service.getStateNameByID(Int32.Parse(search_by_state.Value)).ToString();

        target_url += "&state=" + stateName;
    }
    else
    {
        state = 0;
    }

    if ((Request.Form["search_by_country"]) != "")
    {
        string countryName = service.getCountryNameByID(Int32.Parse(search_by_country.Value)).ToString();

        target_url += "&country=" + countryName;
    }
    else
    {
        country= 0;
    }


    string mainUrl = RootUrl + "/default.aspx?" + target_url;
    Response.Redirect(mainUrl);
}
```

This code generates URL based on the submitted form values.

Page load event is as follows :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //To decode filters
    //To get city
    if (Request.QueryString["city"] != null)
    {
        string aCityName = Request.QueryString["city"].ToString();
        cityID = service.getCityByName(aCityName);
        search_by_city.Value = cityID.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        cityID = 0;
    }

    //To get state
    if (Request.QueryString["state"] != null)
    {
        string aState = Request.QueryString["state"].ToString();
        state = service.getStateByName(aState);
        search_by_state.Value = state.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        state= 0;
    }

    //To get country
    if (Request.QueryString["country"] != null)
    {
        string aCountry = Request.QueryString["country"].ToString();
        country = DLResale.getConfigByName(aCountry);
        search_by_country.Value = country.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        country= 0;
    }


if (Request.QueryString.Count == 0)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            GetProperties(city, state, country);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        GetProperties(city, state, city)
    }
}
```

This all code works perfectly fine when user makes search for the first time.

Say, 1st time user searches for city=1, state=2

it gives out the accurate search results. But when user again clicks on search button with different search criteria, say: city=2, state=2
it doesn't gives the exact search, instead it gives out the results for 1st search criteria!

Can anyone figure out any mistake?

is there any issue in page load event??

Or any changes are required in code?????

This code takes out all the properties & limits 15 properties per page for the purpose of Pagination :

```
  private void GetProperties(int city, int state, int country)
{
    DataTable dtProperties = service.GetPropertyList(city, state, country);
    if (dtProperties.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        last = dtProperties.Rows.Count - 1;

        PagedDataSource pageds = new PagedDataSource();
        DataView dv = new DataView(dtProperties);
        pageds.DataSource = dv;
        pageds.AllowPaging = true;
        pageds.PageSize = 15;

        if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
        {
            pageds.CurrentPageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PageNumber"]);
        }
        else
        {
            pageds.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        }

        if (pageds.PageCount > 1)
        {
            rptPaging2.Visible = true;
            rptPaging.Visible = true;
            ArrayList pages = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < pageds.PageCount; i++)
                pages.Add((i + 1).ToString());
            rptPaging.DataSource = pages;
            rptPaging.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            rptPaging.Visible = false;
            rptPaging2.Visible = false;
            //ErrorNoPropertiesDiv.Visible = true;
        }
        rptProperties.DataSource = pageds;
        rptProperties.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorNoPropertiesDiv.Visible = true;
        rptProperties.Visible = false;
        rptPaging2.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

as suggested by @Chetan Ranpariya, it's working, but pagination started giving an issue. it gives all 55 properties but when i click on 2nd page it gives zero results, ideally it should show next 15 properties.

The code which handles the pagination is as follows :

```
public int PageNumber
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
            return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PageNumber"]);
        else
            return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["PageNumber"] = value;
    }
}


protected void rptPaging_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkPage");
    if (lnk.CommandArgument.ToString() == (PageNumber + 1).ToString())
    {
        lnk.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
}


 protected void rptPaging_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["PageNumber"] = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1;
    GetProperties(city, state, country);
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? Specially `btnSearch_Click` code and check what values you get from `search_by_state.Value` and other controls and what value is assigned to `mainUrl` before it redirects. What type of controls are `search_by_state`, `search_by_city` and `search_by_country`? You need to observe the difference between first URL and second URL.

Comment: after debugging i found out that, after btnSearch_Click all the values getting submitted are right, values assigned  to mainUrl are also fine, but then again it goes to pageload & takes out values from URL (search criteria of first issue). that's the issue

Comment: `search_by_country` what kind of control it is?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya all of the controls are dropdown

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `Page_Load` code. When you directly browse URL with `city=1&state=2&country=3` it works as expected. But when you change the value in one of the dropdown and click the button, `PostBack` happens and PostBack does not change the URL. This executes `Page_Load` first. Since you are checking querystrings first you still get the old values `city=1&state=2&country=3` from the querystring which you are also assigning to the dropdowns by `search_by_city.Value = cityID.ToString();`.

After `Page_Load`, actual event handler of button click executes and at that time controls' values are changed to old ones which creates the redirect URL with old values that's why you are seeing the old search result.

To solve this issue, you should change your code of `Page_Load` to as following.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString.Count == 0)
        {
            // If it is not post back and no querystring parameters,
            // load default properties.
            GetDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            // If there are any querystring parameters,
            // Use them to filer the result and set the control values.
            if (Request.QueryString["city"] != null)
            {
                string aCityName = Request.QueryString["city"].ToString();
                cityID = service.getCityByName(aCityName);
                search_by_city.Value = cityID.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                cityID = 0;
            }
            //To get state
            if (Request.QueryString["state"] != null)
            {
                string aState = Request.QueryString["state"].ToString();
                state = service.getStateByName(aState);
                search_by_state.Value = state.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                state = 0;
            }

            //To get country
            if (Request.QueryString["country"] != null)
            {
                string aCountry = Request.QueryString["country"].ToString();
                country = DLResale.getConfigByName(aCountry);
                search_by_country.Value = country.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                country = 0;
            }
            GetProperties(city, state, city)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to handle PostBack because you are redirecting from the click event. So after redirect when you come to the same page it is not postback. Unless you have anything else to do apart this search realated things you don't need to handle PostBack

Comment: i also have pagination implemented, if i replace code with your suggestions, pagination won't work on next button click

Comment: The solution I provided was based on the problem you explained and the code you shared. You can still modify this one to suit the pagination needs too. If you can share how you have implemented pagination, may be better and suitable solution can be provided.

Comment: i have updated the question with the pagination code